# Why do DDL statements hang frequently?

Tags: postgresql

If we perform alter query (like adding constraint or adding column) or update the column, Postgres hangs and keeps on processing the query taking never ending time.

We have to kill the query explicitly.

Why do our `ALTER` statements frequently get stuck?

Comment: Couldyou provide more information about the context, Is it PG that hangs or your client? What do you see when you check with pg_top?

Comment: Have you checked to see if another session holds a lock on the table?

Comment: You probably have a lot of connections that don't properly end their transactions and linger around with "idle in transaction"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two scenarios in which such a query will hang for a long time:

1. Such an `ALTER TABLE` will require an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, which will block all concurrent activity and will be blocked by all concurrent activity.

   The lock request will be queued at the end of the queue of transactions waiting for a lock on that table, so if these are many and take a long time to finish, the `ALTER TABLE` will have to wait for a long time. Other transactions that request locks on that table later will also hang because they queue after the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

   Note that sessions that are “idle in transacrion” or prepared statements can hold locks for a very long time. It is an error to leave such things lying around.
2. Many forms of `ALTER TABLE` have to either rewrite the table (for example if a new row with a non-NULL default values is added) or scan the whole table (for example if a constraint is added, it will have to be checked for each row).

   This can take a long time to finish if the table is large.

To disambiguate between these two cases, look at the locks in the `pg_locks`system view.

Comment: You might want to add that the reason why the DDL statement can't _get_ the lock is very often careless application code that leaves a lot of "idle in transactions" hanging around

Comment: Good idea, added.